# Why is there still case sensitivity in some programming languages?

Tags: programming-languages, syntax

I don't see any use for case sensitivity in a programming language, apart from obfuscating code.

Why implement this in a programming language?

**Update:**

It looks like [someone you know made a statement on this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/12/the-case-for-case-insensitivity.html).

Comment: Why is there still case insensitivity in some programming languages?

Comment: Even English is case-sensitive in general. Common cited example is polish and Polish which are two different terms whose written forms differ only in case and which have different pronunciations and meanings. IMO its better for the programming lang not to be too clever in this regard and let the programmers themselves come up with appropriate written conventions. E.g. its quite common to write something like `Person person = new Person()` in OO language where the symbol 'person' is a temporary object and 'Person' is a class type.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

While case folding is fairly trivial in English, it's much less so in some other languages. 
If a German programmer uses `ß` in a variable name, what are you going to consider the upper-case equivalent? Just FYI, "ß" is *only ever* used in lower case. OTOH, "ss" *is* equivalent -- would you consider a compiler obliged to match them? When you get into Unicode, you get even more interesting problems, such as characters with pre-composed diacritical marks versus separate combining diacriticals.  Then you get to some Arabic scripts, with three separate forms of many letters, rather than just two.

In the dark ages most programming languages were case-insensitive almost out of necessity. For example, Pascal started out on Control Data mainframes, which used only six bits per character (64 codes, total). Most such machines used the "CDC Scientific" character set, which only contained upper-case characters. You could switch to other character sets, but most had either upper-case or lower-case, but not both -- but used the same codes for both. The same was true of the ancient Baudot codes and such considered standard in the beginning days of COBOL, FORTRAN, BASIC, etc. By the time more capable hardware was widely available, their being case-insensitive was so thoroughly ingrained that changing it was impossible.

Over time, the real difficulty of case-insensitivity has become more apparent, and language designers have mostly decided ("realized" would probably be a more accurate term) that when/if people really want case insensitivity, that it's better handled by ancillary tools than in the language itself.

At least IMO, compiler should take input exactly as presented, not decide that "you wrote this, but I'm going to assume you really meant something else." If you want translations to happen, you're better off doing them separately, with tools built to handle that well.

Comment: +1, was going to say something similar, in my experience most people who whine about this are the same people who don't consider other languages/char sets.

Comment: It's not just English that it's trivial for; it's the whole ASCII character set. The case for case insensitivity gets more complicated when you consider all of Unicode.

Comment: My big question too, if the compiler's going to start noticing different spellings, should it allow you to arbitrarily put underscores in or other "word separators"?  Will it maybe try to "do what you expect" when you misspell an identifier?  How far will it go?  (BTW, [Ada allows underscores arbitrarily inside of numbers](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Lexical_elements#Numbers) for clarity reasons.)

Comment: @Barry: The two are pretty much the same -- almost every other language on earth requires characters that aren't available in ASCII. For that matter, even though we sort of get by, it's really rather restricted even for English -- for example, it forces you to write "coöperation" as "cooperation". Fortunately, typewriters got people accustomed to such restrictions long before computers came along, to the point that few people even consider the possibility of using all the characters once considered necessary.

Comment: @dash-tom-bang: compilers have been written that tried to do things like that (correct spelling and what-not). Experience indicates that it's usually better to get the compiler to run faster and produce better error messages.

Comment: @Jerry I agree completely with you.  It seems like a deep rabbit hole to open the door to compilers trying to divine intent.  (Although at the same time my C compiler can tell me "missing semicolon between X and Y, so why can't it just edit the source and save it back out for me, fixed?)  :)

Comment: @dash-tom-bang: well, if somebody wanted to, they could write a compiler to do that. At least to me, however, it's important to delineate between language X, and whatever happens to be done by implementation Y. The language should remain a language; tools that edit code to produce input that's legal in that language should remain separate.

Comment: The right uppercase of ß is "SS". But as you guess, it is hard to revert. There exist many example of non-reversability, I think greek has some of them, but I am german without greek language skills, so I can't tell exactly.

Comment: @phresnel Or "SZ". Good arguments can be made for both.

Comment: @Vatine: Though, as a native german, I would think that many people here would have problems with "SZ", as it has come quite out of fashion. From my observations, you mostly hear older people referring to ß by "Ess-Zett", younger people usually say "Scharfes S" ("sharp S", "hard S"). Anyways, you are right, and this adds even more to the complexity of the exercise.

Comment: @dash-tom-bang The biggest reason why compilers don't fix problems they report is that they can't correctly identify what the users intent was 100% of the time even in simple cases.  Assume this is code is part of a method in the Foo class:  'Foo myFoo = GetFoo()  AddOneToFoo();` Did I intend to call `AddOneToFoo()` on this: `myFoo = GetFoo(); AddOneToFoo();` or on myFoo: `myFoo = GetFoo().AddOneToFoo();`?

Comment: @BarryBrown most non-English languages need _more_ characters than present in ASCII.  Question is if there is _any_ non-English language that can make do with ASCII only?

Comment: Re your last sentence, that’s a straw-man. This assumption is implicit in *all* compilation, notably optimisation. In reality, you have a well-defined (but not necessarily) trivial mapping of input characters. I agree with the rest of the answer, but the last paragraph is just inaccurate.

Comment: @DanNeely: I have no particular objection to a compiler which will squawk at attempts to use identifiers whose case differs from that of their definition, *provided* that two identifiers which differ only in case are not allowed to exist in the same scope (if `Foo` exists in an outer scope, and `foo` in an inner scope, an attempt to refer to `Foo` in the inner scope should be disallowed), and provided that editing tools can auto-correct case as appropriate.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: If I were designing a language, I would require that identifiers must match precisely to be considered legitimate matches, but must differ in more than case to be considered legitimate non-matches.  Using such rules would imply that a program which was legal under one set of case-folding rules would either be identical or illegal under any other--it would not be possible for different rules to change the semantics of one legal program to those of a different legal program.

Answer (score 122):

Why would anyone WANT case insensitivity? In what scenario is it useful to be able to refer to a single variable as `VARIABLE` in one place, `Variable` in another, and `variable` in a third? Case insensitivity is exasperating. I’d much rather get a compiler error when I accidentally type `VAriable` instead of `Variable` rather than let case-typos like that slip into my code.

In conclusion, many programming languages have case sensitivity not just for historical/inertial reasons but because case insensitivity is a Bad Idea.

Comment: You're looking at it inside-out.  Yeah, referring to the same variable with multiple spellings can be annoying, but it's nowhere near as bad as having two different identifiers referring to two different things, in the same scope, which differ only in case.  Case insensitivity is a good thing because it prevents that.  (Plus, it keeps a simple typo from becoming a syntax error; see the link in the question to Jeff's post on the subject.)

Comment: But I want simple typos to be syntax errors! I don't want simple typos in my code and I want my compiler to help me find them. Case insensitivity makes it harder to find them. Case insensitivity just seems like an excuse for sloppy coding.

Comment: @nohat: I agree, when you type anything other than what you intended to type, a syntax error is a *good* thing.

Comment: @nohat: Since you apparently haven't read the article, it mentions how this is a serious problem in languages that don't compile everything up-front, but still cling to the cargo-cult principle of case sensitivity just because that's the way C did it.

Comment: @Mason Wheeler, I *have* read the article and I simply couldn’t disagree more. I have used plenty of case-insensitive languages and I am constantly exasperated by case typos.

Comment: Absolutely agree with nohat - case insensitivity is a ridiculous idea - and usually the proponents come from people who still yearn for the good old VB/Basic days.

Comment: @Tim: one of the things I hated about Basic was the case insensitivity. I used QBASIC growing up and was constantly irritated by scope issues in larger programs. If I needed a local copy of a parameter I had to name it something completely different, like x_coord1. Numbers in var names like this is a bad idea. With case sensitivity, I could used a convention like capitalizing all parameters to avoid this.

Comment: @Tim: Also, Qbasic would change my variable capitalization if I accidently typed it wrong.

Comment: Sounds funny, considering that most programmers are regularly producing tons of spelling mistakes when writing a simple, plain text and they're arguing that they are dyslectics. (Wondering how many dyslectics are programming for their daily bread.)

Comment: There are cases when one would want case insensitivity. I once had to rewrite a large chunk of code from C to Fortran simply because I only had access to a VT50 terminal (with no support for lower case).

Comment: What I would want would be a spec that would indicate that legitimate code must not depend upon *either* case-sensitivity nor case-insensitivity.  If identifiers that differ only in case may be usable within in the same scope, the someone reading code aloud must specify the precise casing for every identifier; if the speaker doesn't specify the case of an identifier, and the listener types `foo` instead of `Foo`, it's possible that the listener may end up with a program that compiles but has totally the wrong meaning.  If identifiers were required to be distinct in ways other than casing...

Comment: ...then having someone type `foo` instead of `Foo` would generate a compilation error, prompting the listener to ask the speaker how the name should properly be typed.

Comment: "I’d much rather get a compiler error..." What about in interpreted languages? And therein lies the problem. In a compiled language where it catches these, it's fine. In an interpreted language, it's a potential bug that could take hours to debug, while case insensitivity hurts nothing. You say you're "constantly exasperated by case typos" in case-insensitive languages. Why? What is exasperating about them other than they don't look good to you? This is completely your ingrained conventions over logic. Give me one ACTUAL reason case insensitivity is bad. There are actual reasons it's good.

Comment: @dallin the principle is that whether something is a capital or lowercase letter has meaning and significance, and should be treated as such. It's not just that case typos "don't look good", it's that they are indicative of a sloppy approach to coding which I don't approve of. I don't tolerate typos of any kind in my code or my team's code, and a language which has "features" which only serve to encourage typo-ridden code is a language I prefer to avoid.

Comment: @nohat But I feel like it only has meaning and significance because we give it that. There's no inherent significance that I know of between myVar and myvar. As far as I can tell, there's no reason they can't represent the same thing other than it bugs our sense of order, while in reality it's a dangerous source of potential bugs in interpreted languages and a (very) minor time waste dealing with compiler errors in compiled languages. Ideally, my thoughts are a language would not allow myVar and myvar and the IDE should auto change typos, thus having the best of both scenarios.

Comment: @dallin Lowercase letters are not the same as capital letters, so in a semiotic system one starts with the presumption that they represent different things. They certainly *can* represent the same thing, but it's not obvious that they ought to, any more than O and 0 or l and I should represent the same thing.

Comment: The funny part is that while downsides of both Case Sensitive vs Case Insensitive are understood (CS - allows to declare obscure identifiers that are different only in case, CI - allows to recklessly use same identifier in multiple shapes) nobody sees that it's a false dichotomy and you can take best of both:  once declared the identifier must be referred exactly as it is declared, and compiler doesn't allow to declare two identifiers that have only difference in casing ("int x; int X;" - error!). I'd call this style "Case Exclusive", have no idea why no language has implemented it yet.

Comment: @dallin not detecting syntax errors before runtime, is a problem inherent in interpreted languages, regardless of the syntax error. similarly you are out of luck when you add an extra closing brace etc.

Answer (score 28):

In Java case sensitivity is NOT used to provide more options in code, but rather for a very clear and consistent semantic meaning. ClassesLookLikeThis. objectsLookLikeThis. methodsLookLikeThis(). STATIC_VARIABLES_LOOK_LIKE_THIS. Classes.WithInnerClassesLookLikeThis. It does NOT provide greater freedom: **it allows you to pack some information concisely into what is an otherwise overly verbose language.**

I think that in explicitly statically-typed languages with mucho compiler and IDE support, case-sensitivity is a great way to communicate information (e.g., Java). With languages like Ruby, case insensitivity would probably cause even MORE unexpected results, though I'd be open to trying case-insensitive Ruby.

I think that case sensitivity with a strict system does not obfuscate code but actually makes it clearer. Consider possible Java code:

```
      joe blah = new hUf();
```

that's pretty clear, but what about:

```
      hUf.WTF();
```

In Java as-it-is, you would automatically know what this is. In case-insensitive Java, it's ambiguous, so **you'd need to resort to some other mechanism to differentiate classes from instances from packages from methods.** And THAT mechanism would probably make you vomit with how ugly it is :)

Comment: NOOOO! NOT MORE UNDERSCORES!! int package_class_method_var_name?!!

Comment: @Michael, strange how nobody seems to notice that the underscore is a hassle to type.

Comment: it depends on your keyboard. For me (using a French keyboard), _ is easy to type, {} are much harder (using AltGr to reach them).

Comment: @PhiLho yes, I've tried to use that keyboard, it is indeed strange ;)

Comment: Ah, so case sensitivity is the new Hungarian notation.

Comment: I have more than once been subtly puzzled by a variable name in Eclipse having the wrong color.  It turned out the casing was wrong!  Helped catching a subtle bug.

Comment: Case sensitivity is not required to allow categories of identifiers to be distinguished by casing style, provided that one does not attempt to use two identifiers which differ only in case.

Comment: logically true but empirically (socially?) false. If you give people rope to hang themselves, they will change the metaphor willy-nilly, or the casing, as it were.

Comment: It's only "_very clear and consistent semantic meaning_" if the compiler enforces it.  Now, a compiler that **required** class names to start with an uppercase character and method names with lowercase might actually be an interesting reason for having case sensitivity.

Comment: That's kind of spurious: just because the compiler doesn't enforce it doesn't mean it doesn't exist. The conventions do enforce it, and programmers generally follow conventions.

Comment: At least it's not Smalltalk which forces you to start all classes with upper case, or Haskell which does the same thing. That is aggrevating :|

Comment: @Dmitry but when do you ever use the flexibility of starting a class name with lowercase? I would kind of like the compiler to enforce this stuff, myself

Comment: @Dan Rosenstark I wanted to implement a console object in smalltalk to have a class method named log to make it look like JavaScript, instead I ended up creating a WScript class with a class method Echo to simulate vbscript. It's nice to be able to do fun things like that. What bothers me the most is that enforcement is not necessary, if anything it should be optional like option explicit in vbscript.

Comment: This is completely irrelevant to case sensitivity. I can still use camel case or any other case style in case insensitive languages and pack in that same information.

Comment: @dallin you get conflicts, so you can't do `var thisThing = new ThisThing`... basically in a case-insensitive lang you can't reuse the same symbol in a different case.

Answer (score 24):

If nothing else, it simplifies parsing and allows you more combinations for variable/class names.

With case-insensitive parsing, you'd be restricted to having to use unique identifiers, since 'myClass' and 'MyClass' would be the same thing. Alternatively, you'd have to add layers of complexity to your parser to make sure you could determine which identifier is used based on context.

Consider a case like this:

```
XmlWriter xmlWriter = new XmlWriter();
xmlWriter.Write("blah");
```

Suppose the XmlWriter class also has a static method called "Write". Are you calling it on the instance or on the class, if there is no case-sensitivity applied here?

Comment: Thats bad naming convention though. I would strangle somebody if `write` and `Write` were two completely different methods.

Comment: Gotta agree with TheLQ on this one.  It drives me nuts when I'm working in some C library and I see declarations like "HWND hwnd;".  Anyone who abuses case sensitivity like this oughtta be taken out and shot.

Comment: That my point, by naming your instance with the same character but a different case than the class, your code is harder to read.

Comment: @TheLQ the methods have the same case. I was using different cases in the class/variable names as my example.

Comment: @DavRob60 It's probably a stylistic thing, but I disagree. I can see how it could be bad depending on the class name, but more often than not I appreciate similar-to-the-class variable naming down the line when I don't have the variable declaration right in front of me.

Comment: @Mason Wheeler, what about Java's Scanner? Would you kill someone if they did `Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);`, especially if it is the only source of input for the program?

Comment: @malfist: That's a figure of speech, of course.  What I would do, though, if it came across my desk, is reject it in code review and tell them to name it "input" or something like that.

Comment: +1 for 'more combinations', why would we want to be limited?

Comment: @Mason I started saying "should be taken out and shot" mainly because my ex-boss used it so much. He's also a long-term Delphi guy, so maybe it's a Delphi thing!

Comment: @Frank: I don't think so. It's not something I hear a lot from other Delphi coders.  I'm not really sure where I picked it up, TBH. :P

Comment: `HWND hwnd;` is bad not just because of case but because it's completely unhelpful. What the hell is an "h-wind?" I usually do `HWND handle;`

Comment: @Anne Lear,I think this is a bad example. With a case insensitive language you wouldn't have to worry about what method to call because you'd already have a syntax error trying to use a class name for a variable name.

Comment: @Matt Olenik: Ah, true enough. Thanks for pointing it out. That's what I get for trying to think of an example on the spot.

Comment: @Anna - your examples are precisely the reason I don't like case-sensitive languages. People suddenly think that this type of thing is a GOOD idea, when it just makes it harder to read code. That been said, I will always try to keep my identifier case consistant, just because it looks better.

Comment: Just FWIW, case sensitivity (or insensitivity) wouldn't normally affect *parsing* at all. A parser works with tokens. It's up to the *lexer* to translate from some sequence of input characters into tokens for use by the parser.

Comment: I think case insensitivity can be implemented in both the parser and the lexer.

Comment: I don't see what makes this harder to read.  You can enforce a naming convention that classes start with a capital and variables start with a lower case letter, and it's completely natural to use the same-name-different-case.  What's unreadable about that?  (Of course I also can't believe that people can stand case insensitive search, but I guess I just like me some standardization...)

Comment: If you're developing in an environment with decent syntax highlighting, nobody should be confused by `XmlWriter xmlWriter`

Comment: You shouldn't have to RELY on syntax highlighting.

Comment: @Matt Olenik: Well syntax highlighting is already the backup-plan if you fail to notice the capitalization.

Comment: @Matt you shouldn't code *without* syntax highlighting.  I can understand without an IDE, but coding in a editor without syntax highlighting... why would anyone do that to themselves?

Comment: @Davy8 I agree, I wouldn't ever want to. But you should never use naming practices that REQUIRE syntax highlighting to be effective, especially when different people may have different syntax highlighting themes. Not everyone colors type names differently than variable names (Eclipse for Java doesn't, by default).

Answer (score 23):

I don't think it was "implemented" so much as "allowed."  Case sensitivity is the default state of string comparisons; it takes extra work for the compiler engineer to make a language case insensitive, since you need to add in extra code to perform case-insensitive comparisons and preserve the original token names for correct error and warning reporting.

That's almost certainly why it ended up in C; they wanted to make a simple language that was easy to implement a compiler for, at the expense of usability.  As for why it's in modern langauges?  Because it's in C, of course, so it *must* be the right way to do it! </sarcasm mode>

Comment: Plus, I think back in the 60s and 70s when programming languages were being invented, space and speed are VERY important.  We can't afford those extra instructions and space for case-insensitve compares.  It's more of a "that's the way it's always been done" problem in modern languages.  There's no reason for new languages (like C#) to do this.

Comment: @Jay: And yet, for whatever reason, Pascal, which predates C and influenced its design, is case insensitive and still compiles faster. ;)

Comment: @Mason: I didn't think pascal influenced C... I had to look it up.  Basically, they all come from Algol/Fortran!
http://people.mandriva.com/~prigaux/language-study/diagram.png

Comment: Yep @Jay is right, C predates Pascal by two years, but they didn't influence each other. Also I sort of doubt that speed was a real concern for case sensitivity, even in 1970. It was probably just ease of implementation, any performance was a side effect.

Comment: @Matt: Umm... where are you getting that from?  All the resources I've seen date Pascal to 1970 and C to 1972.

Comment: Kids these days.  Back in my day, we didn't have lower case, and we liked it.  6 bits was enough. Of course, now we are all deaf from the SHOUTING.

Comment: @Mason Yes I wrote that backwards. Pascal is 70, C is 72.

Comment: @Mason:  Pascal was designed for fast compilation, among other things.  It was explicitly designed to be easily compiled by a one-pass recursive-descent parser.  Ease of compilation was not a design goal for C, on the assumption that Dennis Ritchie is competent.

Comment: From what I've seen in the documentation, C was designed for the *programs* to be fast, not the compiler. Many C constructs cannot be processed in one pass.

Comment: "extra code"?  You have an uppercase step in the tokenizer...  Need more?

Comment: @Thorbjørn: You need more if you want to preserve the original token name, for example for accurate error reporting or for RTTI generation.

Comment: @Mason, ok, save original version + uppercase step.  Need more?

Answer (score 15):

I like case sensitivity if for no other reason than it makes the code more self-documenting:

```
this is a CONSTANT
this is a ClassName
this is a methodName
this is a local variablename
```

I typically program in Python, but back in my C# days, I found it very convenient to name class instances the same as the class, but lower (or camel) case (as others have said):

```
Thing thing = new Thing();
```

Using case-insensitive languages requires some other convention for this, i.e., some sort of sigil like:

```
Thing oThing = new Thing()
Thing instanceOfThing = new Thing()
```

Which is a "bad thing".

I also find it convenient to grep (case-sensitively) to find reference to a class vs. uses of a variable. With a case-insensitive language, this would be less easy. Same for search & replace.

Lastly, as a programmer, when I see words with different cases, it jumps out to me that they are different things...I rarely have bugs where variable cases were wrong, even in dynamic, scripted languages where a compiler would have helped.

Answer (score 10):

People pay attention to the shape of words before they actually read them. Case sensitivity keeps the shape of a symbol consistent throughout code. I also agree with those above that state that different conventions denote different types of symbols. Case sensitivity and insensitivity can both be abused. Bad programmers will always generate bad code... they will find a way.

Take language as an example. Why do we start sentences and named things with capitals... Is it also because of unix?

Comment: @JUST Comments are meant for seeking clarification, not for extended discussion. If you have a solution, leave an answer. If your solution is already posted, please upvote it. If you'd like to discuss this answer with others, please use [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/programmers). See [the FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq) for more information.

Answer (score 9):

I think for statically-typed lanaguages like C# and Java, it doesn't actually add any value. Because in most cases, you've got an IDE that'll auto-correct case mismatches for you anyway, so at the end of the day, if I type in "VAriable" by accident, my IDE will auto-correct that to "Variable" for me. Add to that the `MyClass myClass;` style conventions and you can see that case-sensitivity is not necessarily a bad thing.

For dynamically-typed languages, there might be more of an argument, since it's harder for an IDE to guess an autocorrection, but in the case of dynamically-typed languages, you've already got so much more to worry about (in terms of typos) that using a consistent casing convention isn't going to add that much more burden.

So yes, while there's no real reason languages could *not* be case-insensitive, there's also no real reason why they *should* be either.

That article from Scott Hanselman about "SignOn" vs "Signon" was about string comparisons, and nothing to do with programming languages. I agree that strings that *users type in* should always compared case-insensitively, but I think that's a different ballgame to identifiers in a programming language.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the "IDE that'll auto-correct case mismatches"

Comment: IDEs are for wimps. I program with pencil and paper, and then scan the code in.

Answer (score 6):

When a language is case-sensitive, I take advantage of it to reproduce conventional case usage in mathematics and science. Here is a list (by no means exhaustive) of some case conventions:

- In probability theory, lower case `f` usually represents a probability density function (pdf), while upper case `F` represents the corresponding cumulative distribution function (cdf).

  Also in probability theory, upper case letters denote random variables `X`, and the corresponding lower case letters denote their realizations `x`, as in $Pr[X=x] \leq  0.05$.

  In linear algebra, upper case letters are generally used to refer to matrices while lower case letters generally are used to refer to numbers, e.g., $A=[a_{ij}]$.

  Unit symbols are written in lower case letters (e.g., m for meter) except for liter (L) and those units derived from the name of a person (W for Watt, Pa for Pascal, N for Newton, and so on).

  Symbols of prefixes that mean a million or more are capitalized (M for mega (millions)), and those less than a million are lower case (m for milli (thousandths)).

Comment: Valid point, but you'd be violating the coding conventions of almost every common programming language out there, which use case sensitivity for their own purposes..

Answer (score 3):

I just figured it was because of Unix and C - but that's kind of a chicken and the egg problem which only the geezers can answer properly.

I use the rationale that the Chickens in "The Easter Bunny is Coming to Town" used when asked whether they came before Eggs.  Because there were chickens on Noah's Ark, chickens came first. Therefore, because GCC runs on Unix, Unix came first, therefore because Unix cares so much for case, C and all its variants and descendants, yea anything that imposes curly braces, cares for case.

There probably is a link between curly braces and case sensitivity too.

Comment: Unix came many years before GCC, but the original BCPL compiler came before Unix, and it generally created the "C syntax".

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the excellent answers given so far, I'd like to point out that case sensitivity gives you also additional "namespaces". For example Perl has some special blocks like `BEGIN` and `END` that run at different times than normal code (BEGIN at compile time, END after the normal program has terminated), and having those as all-caps makes them stand out, and means that the lower case variants aren't reserved words.

One can go even further and reserve all-uppercase names for future use by the language, and don't do any harm to normal programmers, who usually DON'T SHOUT IN THEIR CODE.

Answer (score 2):

"Case sensitive" is always better for technical persons to reduce ambiguity.
Take filename as an example. Dealing with Windows filename is more trouble than Unix filename because filename in Windows is case-insensitive while filename in Unix is case-sensitive.

Back to programming. For class name, method name, variable name, most language do not enforce the naming style rule. Sometimes for the sake of simplicity to do "reflection", we can simply use the "Case sensitive" name to bind to other data source without conversion, or handling the problem of same name but in different case.

Comment: Nonsense.  It only appears to reduce ambiguity because you already expect the case-sensitive behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised by this rant.  Now that nobody wants you to use an underscore or an `m_` in a field name in C#, I've just been using camel case, and if the field name is the same as a public property name, just that the public property name is Pascal case and the backing field is camel case, I figure, "so be it" - that's what the programming community at large seems to want.  It hasn't caused any problems so far.

Answer (score 0):

Especially some programmer come from the early days of BASIC, where a variable name can only be 2 characters long.

And so, when it can be any number of characters, they become very happy.  And along with case sensitivity -- because they don't want to also care about `SomeName` being accidentally equal to `SOMENAME` and cause a bug due to things like this.